# Can't seem to update dynamodb Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an item inside of dynamo db:

```
**User**
username
email
password
acnt_status
```

I am trying to update the account_status to 1 where username = 'Bob', but it wont work. SQL equivalent would be `UPDATE USERS SET acnt_status = 1 WHERE username = 'Bob';`

This is my Java code, but it always throws an exception with a null getMessage():

```
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
                                    .withPrimaryKey("username", "Bob")
                                    .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.NONE)
                                    .withUpdateExpression("set #acnt_status = :val")
                                    .withNameMap(new NameMap()
                                            .with("#acnt_status", "acnt_status"))
                                    .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                                            .withNumber(":val", 1));
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I didn't include it, but late in the code i had a QueryOutcome and realized I had the query return no data so the QueryOutcome was throwing an error.